# Shopify Webhook not working for app/uninstalled

Tags: php, shopify, webhooks, shopify-app

I've created a shopify app with PHP. and registered a webhook for 'app/uninstalled'. Which will remove data from my database.

But when I delete this app the webhook isn't triggering. Because the store isn't removing from my database.

Here is my code:

```
`POST /admin/webhooks.json
'webhook'  => array(
    "topic" => "app/uninstalled",
    "address" => "https://my-domain/apps/app-name/uninstall.php",
    "format" => 'json',
 ),`
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem and what things should I need to edit?

I've tried for a long time but now I'm stuck with this....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with exception handling:-

```html
<?php 
try
{
 $webhook_delete = array(
 'webhook' =>
      array(
  'topic' => 'app/uninstalled',
  'address' => 'https://your-domain/app/delhook.php?shop=shop-name',
  'format' => 'json'
      )
        );
        $result = $shopify('POST /admin/webhooks.json',$webhook_delete);
}
catch (shopify\ApiException $e)
{
      # HTTP status code was >= 400 or response contained the key 'errors'
 echo $e;
 print_r($e->getRequest());
 print_r($e->getResponse());
}
catch (shopify\CurlException $e)
{
      # cURL error
 echo $e;
 print_r($e->getRequest());
 print_r($e->getResponse());
}
```

You can pass store-name with address in link and can fetch on delhook.php or your file.

**Delhook.php**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['shop'])) { 
  //here you can remove store from your database.
}
```

If you get any error then it will print the error.

Comment: I think your code will check if webhook is registered or not upon registering webhook. But I told that I'm able to register the webhook but it isn't trigger when I uninstall the app.

Comment: Basically you want to remove store from your database when webhook is registered. So you can pass a variable with address where you can fetch store and remove the store from your database. i edit my code you can check now. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Mobashir - Please check code now, if webhook will register it will send a parameter to your file where you can code for remove store from database.

Comment: Sorry! it seems nothing has been changed after using your code...Thanks for your help. Hope that your next solution will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that the webhook had been created. In `https://my-domain/apps/app-name/uninstall.php` put these line of code

```
$webhook = file_get_contents('php://input');
$webhook = json_decode($webhook, TRUE);
$newFileName = "something.txt";
file_put_contents($newFileName, $webhook);
```

It will catch the json shopify send when you uninstall your apps and put into file something.txt after that get the info your use to store. Json usually look like

```
{
  "id": 690933842,
  "name": "Super Toys",
  "email": "super@supertoys.com",
  "domain": "super.myshopify.com",
  "province": "Tennessee",
  "country": "US",
  "address1": "190 MacLaren Street",
  "zip": "37178",
  "city": "Houston",
  "source": null,
  "phone": "3213213210",
  "latitude": null,
  "longitude": null,
  "primary_locale": "en",
  "address2": null,
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "country_code": "US",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "currency": "USD",
  "customer_email": "super@supertoys.com",
  "timezone": "(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
  "iana_timezone": null,
  "shop_owner": "Steve Jobs",
  "money_format": "$",
  "money_with_currency_format": "$ USD",
  "weight_unit": "kg",
  "province_code": "TN",
  "taxes_included": null,
  "tax_shipping": null,
  "county_taxes": null,
  "plan_display_name": "Shopify Plus",
  "plan_name": "enterprise",
  "has_discounts": true,
  "has_gift_cards": true,
  "myshopify_domain": null,
  "google_apps_domain": null,
  "google_apps_login_enabled": null,
  "money_in_emails_format": "$",
  "money_with_currency_in_emails_format": "$ USD",
  "eligible_for_payments": true,
  "requires_extra_payments_agreement": false,
  "password_enabled": null,
  "has_storefront": true,
  "eligible_for_card_reader_giveaway": false,
  "finances": true,
  "primary_location_id": 905684977,
  "checkout_api_supported": true,
  "multi_location_enabled": false,
  "setup_required": false,
  "force_ssl": false,
  "pre_launch_enabled": false,
  "enabled_presentment_currencies": [
    "USD"
  ]
}
```